# Visual Studio Code terminal commands not recognised in LInux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm using the following version of VS Code on Linux Mint 20.3 Una XFCE Desktop -

```
Version: 1.71.2
Commit: 74b1f979648cc44d385a2286793c226e611f59e7
Date: 2022-09-14T21:12:14.256Z
Electron: 19.0.12
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-126-generic
Sandboxed: No
```

When I launch the terminal through the menu *Terminal>New Terminal* it cannot recognise any commands for example -

```
sh: npm: command not found
sh-5.1$
```

**npm is installed on my system and is available through the terminal outside of vscode.*

By the way, I get the same result when I try to execute any npm command through the Run menu.

What I've tried -

- using different types of terminal eg/bash, sh, same result
- Modifying the settings to use `xfce4-terminal`, it doesn't work and complains that it can't find the command xfce4-terminal

Also strangely when I navigate to /bin /usr/bin from the integrated vscode terminal the files look different from what I have on my system. For example `npm` and many others are missing.

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: Does this happen on all VSCode instances, no matter what project you have open? Or can it be that you have opened a project that is configured to work in a docker container? See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers.

Comment: Good question! And thanks for the link, actually it always happens regardless of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution! It appears that the integrated terminal overrides the `PATH` variable present in `.bashrc`. To ensure `PATH` is set correctly, click on the settings button circled in yellow shown on the image. And simply add the `PATH` entry as shown. Of course you will need to replace the value of `PATH` to whatever you use on your system *use the output of* `echo $PATH`. Once this is done, reset your integrated terminal and you will have access to all the commands provided on your path!

[image: settings.json]

To run/debug the app (*for Firefox, presumably the steps are similar for other browsers*) from the `Run` menu -

1. Install the required debugging plugin.
2. Get the path to your browser eg/ `whereis firefox`.
3. Add those paths to `settings.json` as shown.
4. Add the configuration shown to `launch.json` as shown, or do it via the `Add configuration` button. *To get to `launch.json,` try to run the App via the Run menu, and you will be signposted there by vscode.*

[image: running/debugging app from run menu]

To view your config changes at anytime type `@modified` into the settings search bar.
[image: view modified settings]